# XSLT: XML to XML with nested attributes

Tags: xml, xslt, transformation

I've got

```
<Level>
    <Stage>
        <Room id="1">
            <Door color="Brown" weight="5" check="true"/>
        </Room>
        <Room id="2">
            <Door color="Green" weight="7" check="false"/>
        </Room>
    </Stage>
</Level>
```

But i need it to transform it to following format with the help of XSLT

```
<Result>
    <Listing>
        <Room check="false">
            <Folder id="1" weight="5" color="Brown"/>
        </Room>
        <Room check="true">
            <Folder id="2" weight="7" color="Green"/>
        </Room>
    </Listing>
</Result>
```

The question is that Room's id should be in nested element descriptor, while nested check should be on the level up. Is it possible to to do with XSLT transformation? How? Could you provide some example please?

Comment: Can we assume that each Rom has exactly one Door? (If the answer is yes, one must wonder why the input needs to nest them - but that's another question...).

Comment: In which case, what logic must be applied to project the `Door/@check` boolean to the parent `Room` - e.g. the boolean on the first child (assumed it has at least one), or only if all child  Door attributes are true, etc?

Comment: It is an invertion @StuartLC mentioned. I'm checking his example

Comment: Then you need to explain **exactly** what the output should be if (a) a Room has no Doors and (b) a Room has more than one Door.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per @michael's comment, it seems that your sample isn't really representative (since Rooms can have multiple Doors), and you will also need to determine the logic on how to project an aggregate boolean representation of all door `check` states onto the parent `Room`.

Here's an example of mapping with multiple Doors, with the logic that all doors must be `check='true'` in order for the `Room/@check` to be true:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="/Level">
        <Result>
            <Listing>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="Stage/Room"></xsl:apply-templates>
            </Listing>
        </Result>    
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="Room">
        <Room check="{count(Door[@check='false']) = 0 and Door}">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="Door"></xsl:apply-templates>
        </Room>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="Door">
        <Folder id="{../@id}" weight="{@weight}" color="{@color}"/>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Input Xml**

```
<Level>
    <Stage>
        <Room id="1">
            <Door color="Brown" weight="5" check="true"/>
            <Door color="Purple" weight="7" check="true"/>
        </Room>
        <Room id="2">
            <Door color="Green" weight="7" check="false"/>
            <Door color="Orange" weight="4" check="true"/>
        </Room>
        <Room id="3">
        </Room>
    </Stage>
</Level>
```

**Output Xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Result>
  <Listing>
    <Room check="true">
      <Folder id="1" weight="5" color="Brown" />
      <Folder id="1" weight="7" color="Purple" />
    </Room>
    <Room check="false">
      <Folder id="2" weight="7" color="Green" />
      <Folder id="2" weight="4" color="Orange" />
    </Room>
    <Room check="false" />
  </Listing>
</Result>
```

Comment: This is correct! What if there will be no doors - could i put a check or paste the null/message?

Comment: I've added a check for no child doors (and Door will be true if there is at least one Door child)

Comment: Alternatively, if you want to omit Rooms with no Doors entirely, change the apply-template to `select="Stage/Room[Door]"`